# Wrapping RelativeLayout in ScrollView Problem

Tags: java, android, eclipse, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I am trying to wrap a relative layout in a scroll view as shown below, however it is not working. I cannot see the last text box which is off screen and cannot scroll down on the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scroller"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="horizontal"
> 
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/namedetail"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundstate"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
android:layout_height="50dip"
android:textColor="#FF000000"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textSize="15sp"
android:typeface="sans" 
  />      
<ImageView android:id="@+id/picturedetail"
android:layout_width="175dip"
android:layout_height="175dip"
android:layout_below="@id/namedetail"
android:layout_marginLeft="75dip"
android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
/>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/infoboxdetail"
android:layout_width="225dip"
android:layout_height="100dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
android:layout_below="@id/picturedetail"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundstate"
/>
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/descriptiondetail"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundstate"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
android:layout_height="50dip"
android:textColor="#FF000000"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textSize="15sp"
android:typeface="sans" 
android:layout_below="@id/infoboxdetail"
android:layout_marginTop ="10dip"
/>  
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: tell us what you are expecting and what is the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with

```
android:orientation="vertical" in relative layout..
```

Comment: I debugged your code and it is working fine ... scrollbar will show it's effect when your view is larger than your display area..

Comment: Thank you for doing that. So I need to set the display are to be shorter.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3236/discussion-between-ohnomycoco-and-vineet-shukla)